# gnuplot contour plot detail

Tags: plot, gnuplot, contour

So, I have a file with 3 columns (and 40000 rows), .First column is x coordinate, second is the y coordinate and 3rd column is "how many" and I want to produce a contour plot from this file. I searched around and I managed to make it work with a solution from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818875/gnuplot-pm3d-with-contour-lines). But the ending result is of really low resolution:
[[image]]

I tried tweaking the line "set dgrid3d 100,100,4" but it doesn't really do much. Any help? The end result should be like this:

[image]

EDIT: Code I'm using

```
set contour
unset surface
set cntrparam levels incr 0.0,0.1,1.0

set view map
set xrange [0:30]
set yrange [0:30]

set dgrid3d 100,100,4

set table "contour.txt"
splot 'this.txt'
unset table

unset contour
set surface
set table "dgrid.txt"
splot 'this.txt'
unset table

reset
set pm3d map
unset key
set palette defined (0 '#352a87', 1 '#0363e1',2 '#1485d4', 3 '#06a7c6', 4 '#38b99e', 5 '#92bf73', 6 '#d9ba56', 7 '#fcce2e', 8 '#f9fb0e')
set autoscale fix
set grid

splot 'dgrid.txt' w pm3d, 'contour.txt' w l lc rgb "black"
```

Comment: how many datapoints do you have? maybe you can provide the data. What is your exact code you are using?

Comment: updated question with the code I'm using. Number of data is not the problem, there's 40000 points

Comment: I know it's now an old post and it might be obsolete. But if you want that people test their suggestions for getting a satisfying answer, you should provide the real data as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the  `isosamples` parameter on your code:

```
set pm3d map
set multiplot layout 2,1

set isosamples 10
splot x*y

set isosamples 100
splot x*y
```

This results in:

[image]

Of course, you're always limited by the sampling of your underlying data, but by changing the `isosamples` maybe you can get closer to the original plot you showed.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237482/samples-isosamples-and-how-they-affect-contour-lines) and [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node191.html). Hope it helps!

Comment: I updated my question with the code I'm using. Where's should I put the command "set isosamples 100", I've tried it and it doesn't change anything.
Number of points are 40000. This is not the problem, because I can make contour plots with another software and graph is fine (using the same file), in terms of resolution.

Comment: What happens if you just do `set pm3d map; set isosamples 100; splot "this.txt"` then change the isosamples?